# How to use axios client to retry on 5xx errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, axios-retry

I am trying add retry to my api call using `axios-retry` module. In order to test I am using `mockoon` macosx client. I have setup the endpoint in `mockoon` to return `502` response all the time. So that I can test the retry.

```
import axios from "axios";
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';

async function sendRequest(method): Promise<any> {
  try {

    // return 502 after 100ms
    let url = `http://localhost:3000/answer`

    axiosRetry(axios, {
      retries: 3
    });


    const response = await axios[method](url);
    console.log('api call completed');
    return response;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('api call error: ', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

(async () => {
  const response = await sendRequest('get')
})()
```

The issue here is, the `axios.get` not completing the execution. Therefore it does not log either `api call error` or `api call completed` messages. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axiosRetry` does not work with axios `0.19.0` (the current axios release) : https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry#note

## Alternative

Use a general purpose async retry function e.g.

```
async function retry<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>, n: number): Promise<T> {
  let lastError: any;
  for (let index = 0; index < n; index++) {
    try {
      return await fn();
    }
    catch (e) {
      lastError = e;
    }
  }
  throw lastError;
}

// use 
const response = await retry(() => axios[method](url), 3);
```

## More

[Source of the retry function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7N8wbrCYqeM).

Comment: how can i introduce a delay between attempts.

Comment: You can use mockswitch app to adding delay.